# File always downloaded as PDF in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, carrierwave

I have defined an uploader in my rails app. The issue I am facing here that, when ever I download the uploaded file it is downloaded as a PDF instead of the actual format of the file.

```
class DocumentController < MyAccountController
  def show
   @agency = current_agency
   redirect_to @agency.document.url
  end
end
```

This is the url of the file. But the file is always downloaded as a PDF

```
"http://localhost:3000/uploads/agency/document/61/document.jpeg"
```

Method to download the file.

```
<script>
 downloadDocument() {
   var url = 'myagency/document',
   fileName = "EngagementLetter",
   file;
   this.$axios.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
   .then(response => {
    file = new Blob(
    [response.data],
    { type: 'application/pdf, image/gif, image/jpeg' }
   );
   FileSaver.saveAs(file, fileName);
   });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue and the following worked for me.

```
      var url = 'myagency/document',
      fileName = "EngagementLetter",

      axios.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data)

        const link = document.createElement('a')
        link.href = url
        link.setAttribute('download', fileName )
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        link.click()
        link.remove()
      });
```

You'll notice that `response.data` is `Blob {size: ####, type: "image/jpeg"}` in the console. You dont have t specify the type.